# MVC4 ignoring parameters

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4, asp.net-mvc-routing

Trying to set up a new site using MVC RC4 web API in Visual Studio 2010, and it just seems to not work: parameter values are never passed to the method.

Everything was working fine in mvc2 but since the upgrade to mvc 4 most of the thing started falling apart.

```
public ActionResult DownloadApp(string id, bool download = false){}
```

I am trying to pass the download parameter but the controller is not catching it

```
RedirectResult (Url.Action("DownloadApp", "Account") + "?download=true");
```

Like I've mentioned, it was working fine in MVC 2. I am forced to use `Queryparameter` that I don't want to use. Is there any way I can make get it to work in MVC 4 like before. The route is as follows:

```
RouteTable.Routes.MapRoute(
                  "Default",
                  "api/{controller}/{action}/{id}",
                  new { controller = "account", action = "index", id = "" },
                  namespaces
                  );
```

Answer (score 5):

Try this way:

```
new RedirectResult(Url.Action("DownloadApp", "Account", new { download = true }));
```

Comment: Interesting... Could you post some more code, where you create and return the RedirectResult object?